# Setting up iPhone Simulator Directory and Xcode Derived Data Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have Xcode 6.2 on Yosemite 10.10.2. I installed Core Data Editor and I need to setup these folders in order to browse trough my databases on my iOS simulator.

So, how can I setup iPhone Simulator Directory and Xcode Derived Data Directory on Core Data Editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem.

First, thank you @heximal, you helped me a lot!

I am new on MAC and iOS development, but I somehow managed to solve this puzzle.

**STEP 1.** - go to [this page](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/) and show hidden files on OS X.

**STEP 2.** - navigate to this( ~/Library/Developer/ ) folder in your Finder

**STEP 3.** - open your Core Data Editor Preferences, and go to Integration tab

**STEP 4.** - click on Xcode Derived Data Directory drop down list and pick Other

**STEP 5.** - click and drag your DerivedData folder (located in Xcode folder) to opened window in Core Data Editor and click Open

**STEP 6.** - apply procedures from steps 4. and 5. on iPhone Simulator Directory (you want CoreSimulator dir)

That is it. Wait for a while for Core Data Editor Project Browser to find your databases and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct you need xCode menu Preferences then select Locations tab

Comment: Ok, but what abbout iOS simulator dir? Where is it?

Comment: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices are you looking for this?

Comment: Good, I found those two folders. They are hidden by default so I had to show hidden files in OS X and I found them. But now I have other problem, when I try to pick those two folders from the Preferences option in Core Data Editor, I can't see any of the hidden files or folders. I dont know how to solve this problem.